# How should I approach modeling these subjective probability estimates?

Tags: mixed-model

In my data about 1000 people have made estimates of the probability of 100 unique events.  On average people forecast on about 50 events, but some forecast on all of events and some on only a few.  About 500 of these people are working in teams of 15.  They see each others forecasts and communicate with each other, but each individual still offers their own estimates).  One question I'd like to answer is how much of the variance in these forecasts is explained by which team people were (randomly) assigned to.  But I also suspect that the share of the variance explained by team will vary by event.  So I'd like to examine that variation as well.  I have a bit of experience with mixed models with lmer, but its not immediately obvious to me how to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the forecasts (or your metric) for each event are commensurate, you will need to make 100 separate evaluations, one per event. For each event $i$ and associated forecaster $j$, you could try a linear mixed model:

$y_{ij} = \mu_i + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\#Teams}a_{ik}T_{ijk}+\epsilon_j$

Where $\mu_i$ is the mean forecast across all members,$T_{ijk}$ is a binary variable indicating whether person j was assigned to team k for question i, with $a_{ik}$ being the team effect for question i. $\epsilon_j$ is the individual effect.

Now, if you make "completed" datasets via imputation (and the forecasts/metrics are commensurate) then you can do an analysis across all questions at once, so each person will have 100 y's associated with them.

I'm not familiar with how to work directly with unbalanced designs, so someone else may have a more sophisticated approach, but hopefully this give you ideas or gets you started.